# Building site on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, github

I'm beginner on rails, heroku and git, but I've done all installation stuffs.
I created two projects on heroku.com, but I don't know how to change them from my PC (the way I looked from help doesn't work such as "$ git push heroku master").
So, how can I edit one of my herokuapp in different computers?

As I understand, I need git commands to bound my projects on PC to herokuapp, and commands to update projects from heroku to my PC (mostly 2 different Win 7 and sometimes iMac). Am I right? Does anybody can tell me how it's works?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't ever used a version control system before you might be in for a steep learning curve.

Git allows you to manage source revision across distributed repositories.  In your case, it might make sense to set up a GitHub account and create a git repository there, then use that as your master repository.  You use git to **pull** code from the master repository to your local machine, where you make your changes.  You commit your changes to your local repository and then push these changes to the master repository.

On your heroku account you then git pull from the master repository to retrieve the changes you made.

This brushes over a lot of detail that you need to know.  I suggest you start googling git tutorials and read up about how git works and how it's intended to be used.

Comment: Seems like "pull" exactly I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are totally new to git and heroku i would suggest you to go through [this](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#sec-version_control)